# Index not hitting while querying

Tags: oracle, performance, index, index-tuning

I have a query on a table tab and this table has a column a:

```
select * from tab where a = :a;
```

but the index is not hitting. Please let me know what could be possible reason (It was asked during an interview).

Comment: Please consider reading the following articles: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)_. Currently your question isn't answerable and will possibly be closed as [**unclear what you are asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Avoid that job. If is one of those companies who try to have a fixed solution for all problems, thats a bad company.

Answer (score 1):

- index on `a` is unusable
- index on `a` is invisible and `optimizer_use_invisible_indexes` is `FALSE` (which is the default value)
- implicit type conversion: type of `:a` is different from type of `a`
- simply the cost of the plan that uses full table scan is lower than the cost of the plan that uses the index
- NLS settings were changed in the session (`nls_sort`, `nls_comp`) and the original index can not be used anymore with those settings

Comment: The `SELECT *` makes the full table scan vs using the index somewhat more likely; there won't be a covering index.